# Formatting the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Is it possible to format the list of Chapters and Page Numbers in a TOC? I would like to remove the bold font face and reduce the size of the font in the TOC to 10pt.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,british,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gill Sans}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.25pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {../img/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}%changed to small caps in headers
%\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalsize}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\small}
%\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalsize}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\small}
  \addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} %for headings
 %\addtokomafont{disposition}
  \chead{Ben Francis}
  \ofoot{} %Author Name
  \ifoot{} % Chapter Number
\lehead{\pagemark}
\rohead{\pagemark}
\cohead{\mytitle}
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\tolerance=1000
\hyphenpenalty=1000
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=5.06in,paperheight=7.81in,
%   verbose,
%   tmargin=0.75in,
%   bmargin=0.75in,
%   inner=0.75in,
%   outer=0.5in,
%   headheight=0.1in,
%   headsep=0.15in,
%   footskip=0.45in,
  twoside}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Tears in the Rain} 
\newcommand{\emptx}[1]{\textit{#1}}

%\RedeclareSectionCommand[
%indent=.25in,
%font=\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde
%font=\fontsize{15}{10}
%]{section}

%\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont\fontspec{Gill Sans}}
%\setkomafont{subsection}{\small}
%\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\small}
%\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize}
%\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalsize}

\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300

\setlength\parindent{8pt}

  \begin{document}
    \title{\mytitle}
    \author{}
    \date{}
  \frontmatter
\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{flushright}
      {\huge \mytitle}
      \par\end{flushright}{\huge \par}
\end{titlepage}

  \begin{titlepage}
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=4in,height=1.5in]{./titrbensig}
  \vspace*{0.5in}
  \begin{flushright}
      \Huge{Tears in the Rain}
    \par\end{flushright}{\Huge \par}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
    \emph{Copyright}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \textcopyright{ 2014 Ben Francis All rights reserved.}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.5in}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\paperwidth}
        No part of this publication may be reproduced, stored in a retrieval system, or transmitted in any form, or by any means;
        mechanical, electrical, photocopying, scanning, recording or
        otherwise, without prior written consent from the publishers. Every
        effort has been made to contact all copyright holders. The author and
        publisher will gladly rectify any omissions.
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.5in}
\begin{center}
    ISBN:
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.2in}
\begin{center}
    A CIP Record for this book is available from the British
    Library.
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.1in}
\begin{center}
    Typeset in \LaTeXe
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\tableofcontents

\addchap{PREFACE}
\input{./titr_pref.tex}     
\mainmatter
\addchap{ONE}
\input{./titr01.tex}
\end document
```

Comment: Can you please post a compilable minimal MWE? Especially for the toc it is not relevant, what you write on your title page, but to actually see a toc, the documents need sections or something similar.

Comment: Do you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the font of chapter entries in TOC to `\mdseries` use

```
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}
```

To change the fontsize of all entries in TOC you can use

```
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}}
```

If the fontsize should be changed in lists like LOF or LOT too remove the optional argument. And if the size of the TOC heading should be changed too use `\BeforeTOCHead` instead `\AfterTOCHead`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apologies I'm still trying to find my way around the discussion board intricacies

Answer (score 1):

As it's impossible for me to actually see your MWE in action (Are you writing it in XeTex or LuaTeX?) and I can't comment on your question either, so I will answer here. I suggest you to use the package `tocloft` of Peter Wilson.

```
%% Control the fonts and formatting used in the table of contents.

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%% Use Helvetica-Narrow Bold (size 10) for Chapter entries

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{%
  \fontsize{10}{13}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{bc}{n}\selectfont
}
```

Comment: Or: `\cftchapfont{\mdseries\footnotesize}` and `\cftchappagefont{\mdseries\footnotesize}`. (Given that the main font size of the document is `12pt`, `10pt` is equivalent to `\footnotesize`.)

Comment: Note that it is not recommended to use `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class.